# Category as subdomain

Tags: categories, subdomains

I am new to wordpress

I need my categories as subdomains i,e. domain.com/category/post to category.domain.com/post

I have tried using wp-subdomains , subdomains, main category subdomains plugins but i have a problem ,
when accessing my site home page all icons (theme icons) are displaying perfectly,
but when i access category.domain.com/post the images that i have included in post are displaying perfectly, but theme icons(fb icon.....,etc)are not displaying...

any help is greatly appreciated

My site: http://onmirror.net

Problem:
http://sports.onmirror.net/fifa/

Comment: There is some issue in your main site also. Some SRC links are redirected to : http://d.pr/i/6qWw+         Also it looks that FB image not found in your directory.

Answer (score 0):

Some of your resources are not loading properly, even on your main domain.

Using Google Chrome, load your main page, open the Elements Panel by hitting the F12 key. In the panel that opens, look in the upper right corner. There will be a red X with a number next to it. That shows you how many errors you have. Click on the X and it will open a pane that will tell you the nature of the errors.

If you do the same thing on the subdomain, you will notice you have more errors. If you resolve the errors on your main domain, you will probably find the reason for the other errors.

[image: Network console]

Comment: Thanks for your help, but my problem is not that, the social icons in top bar, and category icons before category names in left bar are not showing when i visit a post with subdomain,

Comment: I want each main category to have subdomain, is there any way to do that

Comment: The icons that are missing are part of the errors.